# Can't resolve server by fqdn when search domain is enabled

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, opensuse, resolv.conf, resolve

I have a server named `site.dpt.myorg.local`, which i want to access both with short name and with fqdn.
When i try to use short `site` or `site.dpt` form, everything works just fine. However when i use fqdn - lookup works when using `dig` or `nslookup`, but fails when i use web browser, ssh and other tools.

I.e. ssh and ping fail with following error:

```
$ ssh -vvvv site.dpt.myorg.local
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 25: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "site.dpt.myorg.local" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname site.dpt.myorg.local: Name or service not known

$ ping site.dpt.myorg.local
ping: unknown host site.dpt.myorg.local
```

I have a following resolv.conf file:

```
search myorg.local dpt.myorg.local
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

My OS is Opensuse 42.3

Can anyone point me to the cause of this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Are your nameservers configured to handle `dpt.myorg.local`?

Comment: Yeah, nameservers are correct, i'm pinging the same full addresses from other machines in network just fine. On a test centos 6 box with same resolv.conf i can use all hostname forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `local` TLD is [reserved for use with mDNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#section-3) and [should not be used with regular DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#section-22.1).

The proper solution would be to stop misusing `local` in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question: https://superuser.com/questions/704785/avahi-ping-cant-resolve-hostname-but-nslookup-can

the problem was in avahi service, configured by default for .local domain. fixing part of `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` as

```
[server]
domain-name=.alocal
```

solved my problem.

Edit: Ended by disabling avahi since i had no need in it in my environment.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the proper solution is to stop abusing `local` rather than changing avahi (or other mDNS implementation of choice) to operate in nonstandard ways or disabling it entirely (which might be a slightly cleaner middle ground).